# How to automatically run a function after a page loads in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In my componentDidMount(), I am calling an actionCreator in my redux file to do an API call to get a list of items. This list of items is then added into the redux store which I can access from my component via `mapStateToProps`.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        list: state.list
    };
};
```

So in my render(), I have:

```
render() {
    const { list } = this.props;
}
```

Now, when the page loads, I need to run a function that needs to map over this `list`.

Let's say I have this method:

```
someFunction(list) {
    // A function that makes use of list
}
```

But where do I call it? I must call it when the list is already available to me as my function will give me an error the list is `undefined` (if it's not yet available).

I also cannot invoke it in render (before the return statement) as it gives me an error that render() must be pure.

Is there another lifecycle method that I can use?

Comment: You can do that in render or in componentWillReceiveProps. If you are using React 15 then use componentWillReceiveProps otherwise don’t because this method is deprecated from React v16.3. But make sure you do conditional check before accessing list this.props.list && this.props.list.map like that.

Comment: Which version of react are you using?

Answer (score 0):

These are two ways you can play with received props from Redux

Do it in render

```
  render() {
       const { list } = this.props;
       const items = list && list.map((item, index) => {
             return <li key={item.id}>{item.value}</li>
       });
       return(
            <div>
                 {items}
           </div>
       );
    }
```

Or Do it in componentWillReceiveProps method if you are not using react 16.3 or greater

```
 this.state = {
      items: []
}
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
       if(nextProps.list != this.props.list){
            const items = nextProps.list &&    nextProps.list.map((item, index) => {
                  return <li key={item.id}>{item.value}</li>
             });
             this.setState({items: items});
        }
    }

    render() {
        const {items} = this.state;
        return(
           <div>
               {items}
           </div>
        );
     }
```

You can also do it in componentDidMount if your Api call is placed in componentWillMount or receiving props from parent.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this, and in redux store please make sure that initial state of list should be `[]`

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        list: someFunction(state.list)
    };
};
```